# Adobe Air Desktop - Preventing from unzipping to get contents

Tags: flash, air, adobe, unzip

I recently created an Adobe Air APP for PC that was an mp3 player. I want people to use my APP for many reasons. Then placed it on my website for download. SADLY Someone shared it on facebook and said "If you want just the MP3s and not the APP just unzip the adobe air program and you can listen to them in a separate player."

I was very bummed to hear this news. I have adds and donations buttons etc... that one huge the point of creating the app. Anyway  my question:

**IS THERE A WAY TO PREVENT AN ADOBE AIR APP FROM BEING UNZIPPED?** I need to project the images, mp3s etc.

I know for a PC you can put it in an .EXE. That should work right? But what about a MAC. Is there a way to prevent the folder from being unzipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they want to hack it, they will hack it. Something that you could do, which will at least prevent the most basic hacks, is to encrypt you mp3 file. You can then load it into a `ByteArray` and decrypt it within your application, then play it from memory. However, this is not a guarantee that someone will not be able to reverse engineer your code, figure out your encryption password/algorithm and steal your data.

Comment: I think I found a potential "work around" and that is to download the mp3s from a URL and save them on thier local machine with unknown names and have the play refer to these for loading. It works. Also, how do I encrypt an mp3 and do what you mentioned above?

Comment: so you have mp3s packaged together with your app? so its a limited set of mp3s? have you ever thought of why they dont wanna use your application? looks like you are forcing them to do something they dont wanna do. they will find workarounds on your workarounds.